# Linear regression with a different distance (pref. in R)

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

Is there a way to directly calculate the linear regression coefficients in R but by using a different (quasi)-norm instead of the Euclidean?

Comment: Are you sure you mean linear regression when you refer to euclidean distance?  Linear regression is usually a ordinary least squares (OLS) problem, and I'd assume Euclidean distance to be more useful in clustering, PCA or other dimensional projection type problems.

Comment: @Mainard Yep, I would like to reduce the outlier effect by using a quasi-norm $\||\cdot \||_p$ with $p \in (0,2)$.

Comment: This is called $\mathcal{l}_p$ regression. An algorithm was published in 2007 at https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1714.  There are many other ways to address outliers and the better known ones, like IRLS, give you more control over the solution than $\mathcal{l}_p$ regression will.  Thus, if your concern is about dealing with outliers then you should ask about that rather than asking for the implementation of a solution that might not be the best, or even any good.